# How to cross out a line in the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I created a jQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('tr.inactive').each(function (index) {
            var tr = $(this);
            tr.find('td:first').after(function () {
                return '<hr style="position: relative;top: -' + tr.height() + 'px;">';
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

If tr is inactive it should be crossed; this line in a script by an hr added, but alas it is not added to the screen. If you simply put the screen in html all works.

```
   <tr class="inactive">
        <td>
            <h5>
                Add NuGet packages and jump start your coding</h5>
            NuGet makes it easy to install and update free libraries and tools. <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245153">
                                                                                    Learn more</a>
           <hr style="position: relative;top: -66px;">

        </td>

    </tr>
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for jQuery. Just add this to your `.inactive h5` CSS: `text-decoration: line-through`

http://jsfiddle.net/PN3ce/

Comment: I was to answer the same see http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/5mHxD/ but you already did ;)